# Do untagged questions need 'fixing'?

Tags: discussion

The description of the [untagged](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag states that its presence [indicates that those questions need editing](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags/untagged/info).

However, what exactly can be done for those questions?

For example, the two oldest questions on the site are both [untagged](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) and are both asking for rules clarifications:

- [What is considered suprise](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1/surprise-in-world-in-flames)
- [How does DeGray's Pilebunker chip work when trashing Gems of size 2+?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-does-degrays-pilebunker-chip-work-when-trashing-gems-of-size-2)

Presumably, these questions once had game-specific tags which have since been auto pruned.

### If the [untagged](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag is a bad thing

Is it desirable for users that can create tags to recreate the game specific tags?

Or, is the intention that these questions remain [untagged](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) for as long as there is only one question per unpopular* game and then the tag should be recreated?

### If the [untagged](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag is *not* a bad thing

But rather entirely valid, should the description of the tag be changed to remove the part about requiring editing and perhaps state that some questions are expected to be untagged.

Should the requirement for at least one tag be lifted for this site?

---

<sub>*only in terms of number questions on BG.SE.</sub>

Comment: Keep reading the answer I posted to the linked question, "Use whatever tag you wish"

Comment: Ah, apologies, I made the same assumption as the original questioner and failed to read all of the comments. I have changed the focus of my question and no longer believe it is a duplicate, or at least not of the one it has been marked against.

Comment: See http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/930/are-tags-mysteriously-disappearing/1128#1128. The official suggestion is to write a tag wiki, or ask another question. As far as leaving singletons untagged, I think that's fine. Tagging is most useful as a grouping mechanism, and the questions will still come up in the search, with or without tagging.